# Is there an all-in-one post-merge docker-compose Ethereum network configuration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ethereum

So I looked around and found only PoW docker-compose-based local Ethereum networks. Does anybody know of an example of PoS post-merge docker based locally-deployable Ethereum network?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example `docker-compose.yml` to run both GoEthereum (execution node) and Lighthouse (beacon chain).

This is not a full example, but should be able to get you started.

See also [creating jwsecret file](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/135162/620).

The example assumes your service runs on a domain `vitalik.example.com`.

- Fast GoEthereum snap sync is used to get started
- Beacon chain bootstraps itself from Infura (free API key needed)

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  #
  # Ethereum mainnet geth
  #
  # https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go
  # https://githwcat ub.com/Capgemini-AIE/ethereum-docker/blob/master/docker-compose-standalone.yml
  #

  # Primary Ethereum instance
  ethereum:
    image: ethereum/client-go:v1.10.23
    restart: always
    container_name: ethereum
    network_mode: host
    command: >
        --http
        --graphql
        --graphql.vhosts=*
        --http.addr 127.0.0.1
        --port 30303
        --http.port 8545
        --http.vhosts=*
        --authrpc.jwtsecret=/jwtsecret
        --authrpc.port 8551
        --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0
        --authrpc.vhosts=vitalik.example.com
        -cache 8000
        --txlookuplimit 0
        --syncmode snap
    volumes:
      - ./data/ethereum:/root/.ethereum
      # ETH2 beacon chain node secret file for AuthRPC.
      # Share with your beacon client.
      # Generate this file: openssl rand -hex 32 > jwtsecret
      # and share to beacon chain node.
      - ./jwtsecret:/jwtsecret

  # Beacon chain node using Lighthouse.
  # This node does not publicly expose any RPC servers
  # and only connects to above nodes using authrpc.
  lighthouse:
    container_name: lighthouse
    image: sigp/lighthouse:v3.1.0
    restart: always

    command: >
      lighthouse
       --network
       mainnet
       beacon
       --http
       --http-address=0.0.0.0
       --http-port=5052
       --execution-endpoint=http://vitalik.example.com:8552
       --execution-jwt=/jwtsecret
       --checkpoint-sync-url=$INFURA_URL
    environment:
    # Do a full backtrace when lighthouse crashes
      - RUST_BACKTRACE=full
    volumes:
      - ./data/lighthouse:/root/.lighthouse
      - ./jwtsecret:/jwtsecret
```